# Regex including special characters

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to create a regex pattern in .NET for the following characters and my above expression doesn't work and errors out. Any help is appreciated. The pattern should only accept strings with any characters from the following

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 @ # $ € ƒ £ ¥ % & * ( ) - _ + ] [ } { ' ; : = ` . , / \ ^
```

What i have is

```
const string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9\@\#\$\€\ƒ\£\¥\%\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\]\[\}\{\'\;\:\=\`\.\,\/\\\^]+$";
```

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/

Comment: Can you please send the regex pattern for me?

Comment: That's not the purpose here. Nobody is here to code for you, for free.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that link. Hope its free.

Comment: FYI, it's not a C# Regex, it's a .NET Regex.

Comment: Thanks John Saunders. I just fixed it.

Comment: you should only \ escape characters that have special meaning to .net regex. For sure those currency symbols dont have special meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the beginning of the string and overdo with escaping,try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9@#\$€ƒ£¥\%&\*\(\)\-_\+\]\[\}\{';:=`\.,/\\\^]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not make your pattern inclusive and try to match all characters, instead make the pattern exclusive and tell it what not to match.

For example take the hypothetical following with some of your characters in a CSV setting

`£36 %12,`

So we want everything but the comma, so we use a pattern set negation `[^ ]` which will allow us to consume everything but the comma by specifying this pattern:

`([^,]+)`

Which on the above data will provide us with

`£36 %12`

That is the beauty of set negation, is that you specify an anchor *character* and consume everything up to the anchor.

Comment: Thanks OmegaMan for your input.